# Where can I find the setup.py in the 'wheel' pip package?

Tags: python, installation, pip, environment-variables

My wheel package was wrong, so I need to find the setup.py in this pip package. I want to use this command to fix the error `python setup.py bdist_wheel` but I didn't find any setup.py in my windows10 folder. Here the everything in the wheel folder.

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wheel>ls -al
total 141
drwxr-xr-x   5 test Administrators  4096 Apr 12 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 373 test Administrators 81920 Apr 12 14:20 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators    23 Apr 12 14:19 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators   417 Apr 12 14:19 __main__.py
drwxr-xr-x   2 test Administrators  4096 Apr 12 14:19 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators 19075 Apr 12 14:19 bdist_wheel.py
drwxr-xr-x   3 test Administrators     0 Apr 12 14:19 cli
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators 15930 Apr 12 14:19 macosx_libfile.py
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators  4344 Apr 12 14:19 metadata.py
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators  1257 Apr 12 14:19 pkginfo.py
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators   938 Apr 12 14:19 util.py
drwxr-xr-x   4 test Administrators     0 Apr 12 14:19 vendored
-rw-r--r--   1 test Administrators  7574 Apr 12 14:19 wheelfile.py
```

Comment: You are looking at the installed `wheel` library. Which is not the _wheel_ distribution of your own library (or application). You should look at the content of the `.whl` file in your `dist` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already installed package, it doesn't have packaging files including `setup.py`. To find out packaging files download a distribution package from https://pypi.org/project/wheel/ or look into GitHub repository at https://github.com/pypa/wheel

If you want to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in your own package you need to write said `setup.py` yourself. See
https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/ and https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

If you want to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in some 3rd-party package you need to find distribution packages or VCS repository for them.